# Simulating H1 NMR spectra using chemical shift/multiplicity data?

Tags: organic-chemistry, computational-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

I've encountered a number of free programs/internet plugins that can output IR spectra and the corresponding chemical shift/multiplicity data if you input a chemical structure, but are there any where you can input chemical shift/multiplicity data and get an output of at least the H1 NMR spectra?

**Note:** by "chemical shift/multiplicity data", I am not referring to chemical shift tensors (σ). I mean simple data like "1.92 ppm (2 H, m)".

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any software that can transform a spectrum into a molecule. But if you are asking for look up database have a look at [Spectral Database for
Organic Compounds SDBS](http://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/cre_index.cgi)

Here you can input simple data as you asked for like ppm, and then get suggested moleulces as output.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the `R` language, there is a package `SpecHelpers` which draws proton and carbon NMR spectra given input similar to what you describe.  For proton spectra, it is limited to the basic multiplets, there are no doublet of doublets possible for instance.  Disclaimer: I am the author of `SpecHelpers`.